Shade only a middle region of a GeoDisk with minimum and maximum range
I'd like to be able to show a GeoDisk with both a minimum and maximum range specified, rather than filling in the entire disk (from central point to the outer point).
The following code is a minimum working example where I am showing the region I want to shade in blue lines.  If I could subtract the smaller disk from the larger one, I'd have my solution, but I do not think Mathematica can do that...
GeoGraphics[{GeoDisk[{38.8, -104}, 
   Quantity[200, "Kilometers"], {45, 135} ], 
  GeoDisk[{38.8, -104}, Quantity[125, "Kilometers"], {45, 135} ], 
  Blue, Thick, 
  GeoPath[{{39.59, -102.96}, Quantity[75, "Kilometers"], 45}], 
  GeoPath[{{38.01, -102.99}, Quantity[75, "Kilometers"], 135}], 
  GeoCircle[{38.8, -104}, Quantity[200, "Kilometers"], {45, 135}], 
  GeoCircle[{38.8, -104}, Quantity[125, "Kilometers"], {45, 135}]}]

And here's an image:


Maybe superimpose a Graphics[Annulus[]] atop the GeoGraphics?

Got it: Turns out a FilledCurve does this nicely.
GeoGraphics[{FilledCurve[{GeoCircle[{38.8, -104}, 
     Quantity[200, "Kilometers"], {45, 135}], 
    GeoCircle[{38.8, -104}, 
     Quantity[125, "Kilometers"], {135, 45}]}]}]

Example:

